# Security questions about applications and API

Tags: security, ssl, server

So I am close to finishing my first application and API. It will be going live and be ready for market in the next few weeks. I have question about security though that I could do with some advice.

Does the application (http://www.application.com) need an SSL certificate it has 2 way communication with the api (http://api.application.com), does the API also need an SSL certificate?

Or do I just need to SSL the application as that is what will be sending sesitive data?

Answer (score 0):

Only securing your API won't be enough. If the application communicates with the API via the browser (AJAX/XHR) the application is vulnerable via MITM when it's loaded via an unsecure connection. An attacker can alter the loaded scripts so the data is sent to (and receive from) his server.

When your application communicates with the API on the back-end, and the API is not publicly reachable, I would also recommend securing it with SSL. It's more future-proof, it secures information send between servers, and there won't be a problem when you make the API publicly accessible.

So, my TL;DR answer: Secure both, in the strongest way possible. Your user's data, any data, is precious and you're responsible for safely transmitting and storing it. Saving a few bucks a year just isn't worth it.